# Count variables in a loop

Tags: variables, loops, coldfusion

I want to count the variables and show it somewhere in my code. I have a loop:

```
<cfloop query="get_serial">
  <cfif PROCESS_ID eq attributes.action_id> #SERIAL_NO# </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

and its query:

```
<cfquery name="get_serial" datasource="#dsn3#">
SELECT * 
FROM SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW 
WHERE STOCK_ID = #attributes.action_row_id# 
ORDER BY SERIAL_NO
</cfquery>
```

Everything works fine, but I want to count how many variables are displayed exactly. I actually want to do it in this way because I lack of database variables. Actually it is possible to get the amount of these variables from database, I just don't know which variables to use. That is why I want to count it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can do it with a counter in your loop.

```
<cfset counter = 0 />

<cfloop query="get_serial">
  <cfif PROCESS_ID eq attributes.action_id> 
    #SERIAL_NO# 
    <cfset counter ++ />
  </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>Output #counter# times!</cfoutput>
```

**EDIT: to answer your follow up question:**

```
<cfset counter = 0 />
<cfsavecontent variables="myContent">

  <cfloop query="get_serial">
    <cfif PROCESS_ID eq attributes.action_id> 
      #SERIAL_NO# 
      <cfset counter ++ />
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>

</cfsavecontent>

<cfoutput>

  <p>Output #counter# times!</p>
  <p>#myContent#</p>

</cfoutput>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! it is easier than it seems :)

Comment: can u explain me how do i display the `#counter#` in the top of the page if the loop is at the bottom?

Comment: I added that in to the answer - using `cfsavecontent`.

Answer (score 5):

ColdFusion exposes a variable that tells you how many rows are returned in your query, without running a loop to count them:

```
<cfquery name="get_serial" datasource="#dsn3#">
    SELECT * 
    FROM SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW 
    WHERE STOCK_ID = #attributes.action_row_id# 
    ORDER BY SERIAL_NO
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>There are #get_serial.recordCount# rows.</cfoutput>

<cfoutput query="get_serial">
    <p>#get_serial.serial_no#</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another couple answers, just for fun :), although having the counter is probably the best way since you're already incurring the performance hit of using the loop.

```
<cfquery name="getCount" dbtype="query">
SELECT PROCESS_ID FROM get_serial WHERE PROCESS_ID = #attributes.action_id#
</cfquery>
<cfset total = getCount.RecordCount />
```

And using lists, always fun:

```
<cfset total = ListValueCount(ValueList(get_serial.PROCESS_ID), attributes.action_id) />
```

Point being that there are a multiple ways to solve that kind of problem, so have fun :)